# FaceDetector 's detect method not detecting faces in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webapi

I'm working with the experimental FaceDetector API in Chrome (Version 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (x86_64)) on Mac OS (Catalina v10.15.x). I have enabled Experimental Web Platform Features under chrome://flags

E.g link: https://github.com/neil-coutinho/face-detection-censorship

Issue:

Trying to use the detect() method to detect a face from a static image and a video (webcam), In both instances getting back an undefined as the result of detect()

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
const faceDetector = new FaceDetector({ fastMode: true });
```

Need to pass in the fastMode option !!!